# VS Code jump-box setup with SSH keys

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, proxy, public-key

## Establishing an SSH connection via a jump box

Hi everyone, I have been trying to set up my environment on VS Code to run my code from my Windows laptop on a remote Linux server (through my University department's proxy), by following [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh). It is working fine, but every time I connect to the host, I need to enter my password and would like to avoid this by configuring my SSH keys - it seems like I haven't found the proper way to do so.

## Generating the keys

Let's call my local Windows machine `local`, the proxy `host1` and the final endpoint `host2`. I created a private/public key pair on `local`, transferred the public key to `host1` so that it is now in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, and repeated the process by generating a new key pair on `host1` and transferring the public key on `host2`. I followed the instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting) for generating and transferring the keys:

1. Generate key on `local`:
   `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`
2. Transfer public key to `host1`:

```
$USER_AT_HOST="your-user-name-on-host@hostname"
$PUBKEYPATH="$HOME\.ssh\id_rsa.pub"

$pubKey=(Get-Content "$PUBKEYPATH" | Out-String); ssh "$USER_AT_HOST" "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && echo '${pubKey}' >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

3. Generate key on `host1`:
   `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`
4. Transfer public key to `host2`:

```
export USER_AT_HOST="your-user-name-on-host@hostname"
export PUBKEYPATH="$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"

ssh-copy-id -i "$PUBKEYPATH" "$USER_AT_HOST"
```

## VS Code config

I then edited my `config` file according to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/10/03/remote-ssh-tips-and-tricks), which now looks as follows:

```
Host host1
  HostName host1
  User me
  ForwardX11 yes
  IdentityFile C:\Users\Me\.ssh\id_rsa

Host host2
  HostName host2
  ProxyCommand C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe -q -W %h:%p host1
  ForwardX11Trusted yes
  User me
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

It seems that the first jump works fine (I don't need to enter my password twice) but I am still asked for it when establishing the connection. My guess is that I haven't configured the `IdentityFile` properly? When connecting through PowerShell in two steps (i.e. SSH into `host1` and then `host2`), I don't need to enter my password. I would really appreciate any advice!

Comment: The ssh server(s) must be configured to allow public key authentication. I don't know why they wouldn't be, but you should at least verify that they are.

Comment: Thanks @PresidentJamesK.Polk! I think that it is configured to allow public key authentication; I can use the PowerShell to first SSH into `host1` and then `host2` without being prompted for my password. I think that my config file must be wrong..?

Answer (score 2):

I've been stucking in the same situation.I tried a lot ,and finally managed to connect without password prompts. Below it's how I've done it, Hope it'll help.

Suppose I(machine A) want to connect to machine C via Machine B(JumpServer), generate keys using ssh-keygen on machine A, then copy the content of public key file(default as id_rsa.pub) to authorized keys file(default as authorized_keys in .ssh folder) of both machine B and machine C(or using ssh-copy-id if available). At last the IdentityFile field of both hosts of machine B and machine C in the config file(host1 and host2 in your case), fill them with ~/.ssh/id_rsa or C:\Users\your_user_name.ssh\id_rsa(the private key you generate on machine A ).

Finally it connects as expected.(I guess in this siutation but not for sure that the identity file in the local machine A is always the subject to connect, so machine B and machine C need to use the identity of machine A for all authorizations)

Answer (score 0):

I met exactly the same situation, that is making this ssh connection: local (Windows) -> host1 (Linux) -> host2 (Linux)

The problem here is that for the second jump to host2, the ProxyCommand "ssh.exe -q -W %h:%p host1" actually looks for host2's IdentityFile "~/.ssh/id_rsa" on local. Because the keys you generated on host1 is different from the one on local, using the key on local would fail to make the second jump.

Solutions:

1. Simply use the same key for two jumps. Copy the id_rsa.pub on local to host2's authorized_keys.
2. Copy the key files on host1 to local, rename them and fill host2's IdentityFile with the path of the key file on local.
3. Referring to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/337274/ssh-from-a-through-b-to-c-using-private-key-on-b), modifying the ProxyCommand may enable ssh to use the key on host1 during the second jump. However, I haven't been able to make it work on my Windows local machine.